Android - Firebase events not showing up in some devices
I have an app with both Homolog and Production flavors. In the Homolog flavor, I use the following command to connect to Firebase Debug View:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.exampleofpackage.homolog

This allows me to see real-time events in Firebase Realtime without any issues. However, in the Production flavor (with the package name com.exampleofpackage), I don't run this command, yet I can still see real-time events in Firebase.
The problem arises when I build the Homolog flavor, install it on a physical device without running the adb command, and find that Firebase events are not sent. Even after the scheduled upload time, these events are not reflected in Firebase Dash or Explorer report.
Why does Firebase Analytics work without the adb command in Production but not in Homolog? Am I missing any configuration or misunderstanding how Firebase Analytics should work? I want to ensure that events are sent to Firebase regardless of whether I run the adb command or not.

Is proguard enabled for Production builds? If so, try to disable and check if you can receive Firebase events. This is to make sure proguard is not misconfigured for Firebase.

production is doing fine. The problem here is with some build in homolog. Firebase sends events in packages, right? It appears to not sent in some devices, I don't know why.

Try adding this after initializing firebase
val collectionEnabled = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled

Then print its value.
If the value is false then add this after firebase initialization add this line
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)


Hey! I'm not able to find isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled in Crashlytics v18.3.7. Anyway, how could this Crashlytics boolean affect the functioning of analytics?
